# SonarQube4.4 surefire sensor not getting executed for Grails Project

Tags: grails, groovy, sonarqube

I have couple of non  mavenized Grails Project (2.2.1 and 2.3.5 versions). I can generate Unit test results (spock test) in XML format.
But these results are not getting published in SonarQube 4.4 version. with Groovy 1.0.1 plugin. Sonar can publish the coverage report.
Below are the sonar properties.

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=grails-app,src

sonar.tests=test\unit

sonar.language=grvy

sonar.junit.reportsPath=\target\test-reports

I have tried all combination of (relative / absolute) path for reportsPath and tests.

On checking the logs, I dont see Surefire Senor being executed at all. There is a similar issue in the tracker,
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARGROOV-2?jql=project%20%3D%20SONARGROOV%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Major%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC
But in this scenario, surefire sensor at least gets called /executed but with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I went past this issue after removing `sonar.language=grvy` property. In this case source files are both in Java and groovy language. 
Sonar itself picked the language and surefire sensor did get executed with the 'Resource not found; error as mentioned in the above JIRA issue.

I am wondering if this issue is because of multi-language project.